# tryCatch() function to save warning message AND error message in r

Tags: r, loops, try-catch, simulation

my previous question was:
I am simulating multilevel data and fitting it to various Multilevel models.

I want to make a function that if there is any error (such as "failed to converge" or "singular fit"), I want to save it.

For example, my model is

lmer(y~ x1 + x2 + (1|pid), data=sim_data).

and here are many conditions so various data will be fitted into this model.

How can I save the error or warning message as a whole in the dataframe or list?

(like, first dataset -> no error, second dataset -> converge error...etc)

and some people gave me good answer to it.
However, the answers to this question were about error message, but not warning message.

```
for( i in 1:10){



catch$error[i]<-tryCatch((y~ x1 + x2 + (1|pid), data=sim_data),
                error=function(e) e$message,
                warning=function(w) w$message)
}
```

with this code, can I extract warning and error message both?
and it seems like generating following error

Error in results$MLM0warning1[i] <- tryCatch(model_null(ind_sim_data),  :
incompatible types (from S4 to character) in subassignment type fix

> 

Comment: Can you provide a functioning **minimal** reproducible example? I can't see how it is possible that the code you show causes the error message you say it generates...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72024496/save-the-error-message-and-warning-message-using-trycatch-function-in-r